# ASP.NET MVC - Calling an Action through jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, action

I've a quick question. 
To call an action through jQuery (to use AJAX), do i have to create a new Action returning json type or is there anyway to use the same action for http request (post) and jQuery too?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the data returned.

Say, your actions returns **Html**, using jQuery, you can put the html returned from the server:

```
$.ajax('/url/', function(data){
    $('#elementID').html(data);
})
```

Alternatively, you can use the jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load) method:

```
$('#elementID').load('/url');
```

If your action returns a **redirect**, and you want the client page to redirect to a url, then yes, you need to create a new action that will return Json:

```
public JsonResult SomeAction()
{
    return Json(new {redirect = true, url = "/Path/ToRedirect"});
}
```

And using jQuery:

```
$.ajax('/url/', function(data){
    if(data.redirect) {
        window.location = data.url;
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same action:

```
$.post(
    '/controller/action', 
    { field_a: "Value a", field_b: "Value b" }, 
    function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
);
```

With **ajax**, you usually want **partial views** or **json** as a return value. With **regular post**, **full html page**. Why do you want to use the same action in ajax and regular post?

Comment: Thanks. I'm now using the Request.IsIsAjaxRequest()) to see if i return a View or other values.

Comment: Because i just need to return a string, and i want to first call it from javascript. If javascript is disabled, then i use the form.